# How to a SharePoint Approval Workflow with multiple If Conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval

I am very new to SharePoint.

I am tasked with making an Approval workflow that has multiple status changes

The Status levels are: Major, Minor, Standard, Freeze, Emergency, Exception and Vendor.

- When the condition is Major, the COO receives a notifictation email,
  The CIO, IT manager, Section Manager receive an approval email.
- With Minor, the CIO receives a notification email and IT manager
  receives an Approval email, Standard the IT manager receives a
  Notification email.
- And for the rest of the status: Freeze,Emergency,Exception, and
  Vendor, they all are suppose to receive an Approval email.

This is what I have:

```
If Current Item: Company equals Major

Send Email
then Send Email

Else
If Current Item: Company equals Minor

Send Email
then Send Email

Else

If Current Item: Company equals Standard    
Send Email

Else
If Current Item: Company equals Freeze

Send Email

Else
If Current Item: Company equals Exception

Send Email

Else
If Current Item: Company equals Emergency

Send Email

Else
If Current Item: Company equals Vendor

Send Email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to help you:
[Need help on nested If-Else workflow statement](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149322/need-help-on-nested-if-else-workflow-statement)

Also, why do you have an else if inside your else? In your else statement, just say else email the approval message to x,y,z (x,y,z being COO, CIO, IT Manager, Section Manager)

Comment: I guess, I'm asking if I'm the right track and how to I send an Approval message after the notification message. Since this is a custom approval workflow.

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken you can send different email messages with whatever you want inside each of them.

Comment: How do you create a Approve or Reject option then?

Comment: I'm not 100% on approval workflows... Do they have an Approve/Reject button within the email? Regardless, you should be able to add an Email command before the approval email is sent in order for you to notify the proper person

Comment: No, they don't have an Approve/Reject button, that ability in outlook exists with the out of the box workflow.

Comment: Okay so you can maybe then copy the shortcuts to the Approve and Reject buttons for the SP List and put those in a custom email for Approvals - edit: and format as HTML so you don't get an ugly looking link, but you have your own Hyperlink text